# CSS FlexBox Horizontal Mansory

Tags: html, css, flexbox, masonry

I am trying to get my app to look like this:

https://stock.adobe.com/search?load_type=search&k=dogs&native_visual_search=&similar_content_id=

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/320/240"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/320/240/paris"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/320/500/cat"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/320/300/dog"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/520/240/girl"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/320/240/boy"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/320/240/piano"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/1020/400/rome"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
    <img class = "image" src = "https://loremflickr.com/100/40/london"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-content: flex-end;
}

.container .item {
    margin: 10px;
    flex: auto;
}

.container .image {
    display: block;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    height: 180px;
    object-fit: cover;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qq137/7rsk5tfc/

A few issues I noticed with my implementation is when I use `object-fit: cover`, it cuts off part of the image and stretches the images to the edge of the div. I have tried using `object-fit: contain` which captures the whole image. However, it creates a lot of white space surrounding the image which I want to avoid. Anyone know how I would be able to make my list of images look like the one I shared in the link above? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Edit -  I take that back. The sample you provided is using thumbnail images rather than the full image. That might be the best way to handle this if the other options don't seem to work for you.

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet, see we have with what to work

Comment: @LGSon I updated the post with working code and a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

The Adobe-Site solves this, by changing the overall size of the images by `+-5%` which gives the impression, that the images fit better. This is done using some JavaScript embedded into the Website.

As far as I know pure CSS doesn't allow you to automatically resize Containers (or images) in such a way ...

Based on:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp